# GeoDjango - LineStringField - how to use it? Where do I find documentation?

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

Good day everyone.

I'm using Django 1.6 with GeoDjango and Postgresql+PostGIS backend.
I want to use LineStringField to save some routes.
But I can't find any documentation about how to do it. I have model, have LineStringField attribute - but what to do next?

Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#linestringfield are only class names, nothing else.
I also tried to google some examples, but it wasn't successful.
Can you please point me where to search for it?
And also I'll highly appreciate some examples of code - like creating object of model with LineStringField, saving it to DB and then getting points from it (to display on the map).

P.s. Please sorry for my english.

Comment: Start by understanding [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (WKT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it myself. We need just to use coords property of LineStringField, like this:

```
>>> event.route.coords
((15.732421875, 8.5775756835938), (10.986328125, 3.3041381835938), (3.779296875, 10.862731933594), (-1.58203125, 7.8744506835938), (-4.74609375, 14.114685058594))
>>> event.route.x
[15.732421875, 10.986328125, 3.779296875, -1.58203125, -4.74609375]
>>> event.route.y
[8.5775756835938, 3.3041381835938, 10.862731933594, 7.8744506835938, 14.114685058594]
>>> event.route.json
'{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 15.732421875, 8.5775756835938 ], [ 10.986328125, 3.3041381835938 ], [ 3.779296875, 10.862731933594 ], [ -1.58203125, 7.8744506835938 ], [ -4.74609375, 14.114685058594 ] ] }'
```